# postgres random using setseed

Tags: postgresql, random, sample, random-seed

I would like to add a column with a random number using `setseed` to a table.

The original table structure `(test_input) col_a,col_b,col_c`

Desired output `(test_output) col_a, col_b, col_c, random_id`

The following returns the same `random_id` on all rows instead of a different value in each row.

```
select col_a,col_b,col_c,setseed(0.5),(
     select random() from generate_series(1,100) limit 1
     ) as random_id 
from test_input
```

Could you help me modify the query that uses `setseed` and returns a different `random_id` in each row?

Answer (score 8):

You have to use [`setseed`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) differently. Also `generate_series()` is misued in your example. You need to use something like:

```
select setseed(0.5);

select col_a,col_b,col_c, random() as random_id from test_input;
```

If you want to get the same random number assigned to the same row, you will have to sort rows first, quoting [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html):

> If the ORDER BY clause is specified, the returned rows are sorted in
>   the specified order. If ORDER BY is not given, the rows are returned
>   in whatever order the system finds fastest to produce.

You can use:

```
select setseed(0.5);

select *, random() as random_id from (        
select col_a,col_b,col_c from test_input order by col_a, col_b, col_c) a;
```

Here I assume that combination of `col_a, col_b, col_c` is unique. If it's not the case, you will have to first add another column with unique ID to the table and sort by this column in the query above.

Comment: Thanks, I gave this a try.  However, if you run this query multiple times with the same setseed(0.5) the random_id changes.  Do you know how to prevent this so I am able to replicate the sample?

Comment: Having an application serving concurent requests from multiple users when each of them tries to set his personal seed and perform a select basing on that seed must both select queries be run in a transaction? What should be the isolation level? Can we combine two selects in one instead?

Comment: @Kolyunya I have no idea. Maybe it would be better to create new question and refer to this.